# How do I get my spinner to have a dropdown menu without the popup?

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I want my spinner to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJtx1.png

but instead my spinner looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcGBa.png

How do I make it appear like the first one?

Here is the code.

```
public void additemsonSpinner1()
{
    spinner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.pusharr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1 );
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

Comment: The one from your first screenshot is from the Holo theme. The second screenshot is from Android 2.x, which does not have the Holo theme.

Comment: So on older firmwares, (APi level 9) it is not possible then?

Comment: it should be, if you use actionbarsherlock to back-port holo.  Although I haven't tested this myself.

Answer (score 0):

> So on older firmwares, (APi level 9) it is not possible then?

You are welcome to try [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere), or see if there is another backport of the Holo-style `Spinner`.

However, bear in mind that *users* of Android 2.x devices may not realize what a Holo-style `Spinner` is, since they do not see them in other apps. I recommend sticking with widgets the user will recognize wherever possible.